# Question regarding conditional sentences

Tags: conditionals

" If you are coming to the races, bring that pretty mermaid of yours"
I wonder if someone could tell me the type of conditional sentence was used in the above-mentioned example?
Present tense was used in two clauses of the sentence which is similar to zero type conditional sentence but it definitely isn't a scientific fact!
Thank you for your assistance

Comment: There is no problem here.  The request (imperative) in the apodosis shows that the requestee has not yet set out and that therefore this use of “are coming” refers to a future intention, a normal usage.  It is tricky for learners of English but quite familiar.   Imperatives also refer to the future.  English is like that.  It’s verbs are not inflected in the way many other languages are.

Comment: The categorization of conditionals is not something done by most native speakers. It's a generalization that is often incomplete or confusing (mostly only provided by ESL teachers and texts), and it's certainly not a strict rule. It serves only as a guidepost.

Comment: Yes, present tense is used with future meaning, which is fine. Grammarians don't talk of 'zero conditionals' and the like, but of open and remote conditionals. The former is typically neutral as to whether the condition is or will be met, while the latter is used when the condition is not fulfilled or presented as a relatively remote possibility. In your example (assuming that "mermaid" is being used figuratively) it can only be an open conditional.